Blazor css multiple styling for same element type
I need to implement different styles for one type of element in my project's page. But I am not able to have more than one fully functional styling.
In this example I have my PartPage.razor with its PartPage.razor.css. and I am implementing two identical styles with different naming, trying to get the same result while implementing through different style names:
PartPage.razor
@page "/part"
<th>
    <label class="form-label-another-label">SomeLabel</label>
    <label class="form-label">SomeLabel</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SomeText" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control-another-control" placeholder="SomeText" />
</th>

PartPage.razor.css
.form-label{
    color: aqua
}

.form-label-another-label {
    color: aqua 
}

.form-control {
    color: #077df2;
    background: #f2f0f0;
}

.form-control-another-control {
    color: #077df2;
    background: #f2f0f0;
}

and this is what it does in the app:
blazor app
It seems like it works allright for text adjustment, but not for the form control. Why is that? Is there a way how to have two stylings for same element?
The css is correctly connected to the razor page as this:
page css

The problem is that you are using a CSS class that is already available in blazor by default:

If you rename form-control to something different, e.g. form-control1 (in CSS and in HTML) the result will look like this:

So watch out for already used CSS class names and remember the browser inspection tool is your friend in the web :-)

Hi, thank you for your answer why this happens. However, I also need answer to my second question: " Is there a way how to have two stylings for same element?" as my goal is to have two separate stylings for form-control in one CSS file. If yes, how do I make it?

Hi @user0, I think you are still not understand Gabriel Weidmann's  answer. You can check my answer below.

Blazor uses Bootstrap by default. form-control is the default Bootstrap css style, so that the element applies the build-in style which caused the difference.
A quick way is avoid using Bootstrap default css style name, change like below:
.form-label {
    color: aqua
}

.form-label-another-label {
    color: aqua
}

.form-control-custom {
    color: #077df2;
    background: #f2f0f0;
}

.form-control-another-control {
    color: #077df2;
    background: #f2f0f0;
}

Then use it in the view:
<th>
    <label class="form-label-another-label">SomeLabel</label>
    <label class="form-label">SomeLabel</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control-custom" placeholder="SomeText" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control-another-control" placeholder="SomeText" />
</th>


I see now, probably I have specified the question in a bad way. In this case, I would like to implement the bootstraps settings to my custom one and then "override" certain values. something like:
.form-control-another-control {
//here somehow inherit from default .form-control and add/override certain values
color: #077df2;
background: #f2f0f0;
}

Hi @user0, Yes, just custom one is very easy. For overriding styles, you may write all of the default css class/id in the file, then override it with new value and end with !important .
